# Error requestFeature() AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alertdialog

Tengo un AlerDialog en mi App, el problema principal es que en versiones de Android Nougat y posterior este funciona perfectamente pero en Marshmallow e inferior el AlertDialog me da este error: `requestFeature() must be called before adding content` pero en ningún momento en mi actividad he llamado a `requestWindowFeature`. He aqui mi código:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return createRadioListDialog();

}

public android.app.AlertDialog createRadioListDialog() {
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[3];

    items[0] = "Voy a asistir";
    items[1] = "No voy a asistir";
    items[2] = "Aún no lo sé";

    builder.setTitle("Asistencia")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == 0) {
                        asistenciaD = String.valueOf(1);
                        guardarMeta();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Main_Fragment_Asistencia(), "MainFragment")
                                .commit();


                    }if (which == 1) {
                        asistenciaD = String.valueOf(2);
                        guardarMeta();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Main_Fragment_Asistencia(), "MainFragment")
                                .commit();


                    }if (which == 2) {
                        asistenciaD = String.valueOf(0);
                        guardarMeta();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Main_Fragment_Asistencia(), "MainFragment")
                                .commit();

                    }

                }
            });

    return builder.create();
   }
}
```

Gracias por vuestra respuesta!

Fragment Entero:

```
       /**
       * Fragmento con diálogo básico
        */
 public class SimpleDialog extends DialogFragment {
  /*
 Etiqueta de depuración
  */


/*
Controles
*/
private String asistenciaD;


/*
Valor del argumento extra
 */
 String id;

/**
 * Es la meta obtenida como respuesta de la petición HTTP
 */
private Meta_Asistencia_si_no metaOriginal;

/**
 * Instancia Gson para el parsing Json
 */
private Gson gson = new Gson();




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflando layout del fragmento


        Log.v("correcto", "si");

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_form, container, false);




    // Obtención de instancias controles


    Bundle mArgs = getArguments();
     id = mArgs.getString("miId");
    Log.v("cii", "siii");



    // Obtener valor extra


    if (id != null) {
        cargarDatos();
    }

    return v;
}

/**
 * Obtiene los datos desde el servidor
 */
private void cargarDatos() {
    // Añadiendo idMeta como parámetro a la URL
    String newURL = Constantes.GET_BY_ID;

    // Consultar el detalle de la meta
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(
            new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET,
                    newURL,
                    null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            // Procesa la respuesta GET_BY_ID
                            procesarRespuestaGet(response);
                            Log.d("suceeful", String.valueOf(10));
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }
            )
    );
}

/**
 * Procesa la respuesta de obtención obtenida desde el sevidor     *
 */
private void procesarRespuestaGet(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        String estado = response.getString("estado");

        switch (estado) {
            case "1":
                JSONObject meta = response.getJSONObject("meta");
                // Guardar instancia
                metaOriginal = gson.fromJson(meta.toString(), Meta_Asistencia_si_no.class);
                Log.d("suceeful", String.valueOf(20));
                // Setear valores de la meta
                break;

            case "2":
                String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");
                // Mostrar mensaje
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        mensaje,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Enviar código de falla
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                // Terminar actividad
                getActivity().finish();
                break;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * Compara los datos actuales con aquellos que se obtuvieron
 * por primera vez en la respuesta HTTP
 *
 * @return true si los datos no han cambiado, de lo contrario false
 */
public boolean validarCambios() {
    return metaOriginal.compararCon(obtenederDatos());
}

/**
 * Retorna en una nueva meta creada a partir
 * de los datos del formulario actual
 *
 * @return Instancia {@link Meta}
 */
private Meta_Asistencia_si_no obtenederDatos() {

    String titulo = asistenciaD;


    return new Meta_Asistencia_si_no("1", titulo);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); // Contribución a la AB

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:// CONFIRMAR
            if (!validarCambios())
                guardarMeta();
            else
                // Terminar actividad, ya que no hay cambios
                getActivity().finish();
            return true;






    }
    ;

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Guarda los cambios de una meta editada.
 * <p>
 * Si está en modo inserción, entonces crea una nueva
 * meta en la base de datos
 */
private void guardarMeta() {

    // Obtener valores actuales de los controles



    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();// Mapeo previo


    map.put("asistenciaD", asistenciaD);
    map.put("id_musico", id);

    String newURL = Constantes.UPDATE;



    // Crear nuevo objeto Json basado en el mapa
    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(map);

    // Depurando objeto Json...
    Log.d("TAGK", jobject.toString());
    Log.v("prueba", String.valueOf(9));

    // Actualizar datos en el servidor
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(
            new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
                    newURL,
                    jobject,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.v("prueba", String.valueOf(1));
                            procesarRespuestaActualizar(response);

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            Log.d("error_volley", "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

            ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8" + getParamsEncoding();
                }
            }
    );

}


/**
 * Procesa la respuesta de actualización obtenida desde el sevidor
 */
private void procesarRespuestaActualizar(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        // Obtener estado
        String estado = response.getString("estado");
        // Obtener mensaje
        String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");

        switch (estado) {
            case "1":
                // Mostrar mensaje
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        mensaje,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Enviar código de éxito
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                // Terminar actividad
                getActivity().finish();
                break;

            case "2":
                // Mostrar mensaje
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        mensaje,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Enviar código de falla
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                // Terminar actividad
                getActivity().finish();
                break;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



public SimpleDialog() {
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return createRadioListDialog();

}

public android.app.AlertDialog createRadioListDialog() {
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[3];

    items[0] = "Voy a asistir";
    items[1] = "No voy a asistir";
    items[2] = "Aún no lo sé";

    builder.setTitle("Asistencia")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == 0) {
                        asistenciaD = String.valueOf(1);
                        guardarMeta();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Main_Fragment_Asistencia(), "MainFragment")
                                .commit();


                    }if (which == 1) {
                        asistenciaD = String.valueOf(2);
                        guardarMeta();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Main_Fragment_Asistencia(), "MainFragment")
                                .commit();


                    }if (which == 2) {
                        asistenciaD = String.valueOf(0);
                        guardarMeta();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Main_Fragment_Asistencia(), "MainFragment")
                                .commit();

                    }

                }
            });

    return builder.create();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Es muy importante siempre llamar [requestFeature()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature(int)) después de  [setContentView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)).**

Ya que solo puedes habilitar las funciones de pantalla extendida cuando hayas configurado el contenido de la actividad mediante [setContentView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)).

**En este caso asegura de crear el `AlerDialog`, después de haber llamado [setContentView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)).**

Comment: La cosa es que el AlertDialog está en un fragment..

Comment: Agrega el Fragment

Comment: He añadido el fragment entero. Al principio de la actividad principal he añadido requestWindowfeature y nada